# How do I create dynamic combo box in Java which adds and removes when clicking the button?

Tags: java, swing, combobox

[image: combo box]

Hi. I want to make a dynamic combo box with the example above, which when pressing "+", new combo box appears below and when pressing "-", the combo box disappears.

How do I do this in Java? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ActionListeners for the button you need code like:

```
panel.add( another panel containing combo box and buttons)
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

or

```
panel.remove( the current panel containing the remove button)
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```